# Drupal cron is running very frequently

Tags: caching, cron

Drupal cron is running every 10 minutes in my site but i have set-ed 1 day time for cron, 
i have cleared cache and fix all the major php error logs, please help me how to fix this issue.

Comment: Check server cron, if you've configured Drupal Cron in it.

Answer (score 0):

> i have set-ed 1 day time for cron

Presumably you mean you've set the "poor man's cron" value at admin/config/system/cron to 1 day - that value controls how often Drupal will run cron itself as a reaction to people actually visiting pages; it's not full-automated, hence "poor man's".

Assuming the value is being persisted (i.e. you don't have a global conf override or something for that var), then Drupal will respect it, and only run cron itself when more than a day has passed since the last run.

If it's still running every 10 minutes, then you have another process somewhere doing that - not Drupal.

Check your crontab/pingdom account/your usual alternative to find the culprit. If it's being invoked via URL, not drush/other script via crontab, then you can enable/inspect access logs to get an idea of where the request is coming from. Pingdom's IP ranges are public, for example, so you'd be able to determine if it's coming from there easily enough.

Comment: Thanks Clive, I set-ed 1 day cron after when issue comes, previously it was 1 hour set, for checking purpose i set 1 day.

Comment: That value's pretty much irrelevant if you have another process invoking cron externally

Comment: issue fixed now.. . The problem was that our cron-scheduler-key got public, and some unknown source is hitting our live serve every 10 minutes. This is in-turn running the cron and clearing the cache every 10 minutes a visitor visits the site. so i changed the cron key and its working fine.